# How can I model this json in the right way with Realm?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, realm

This is my first time with [Realm](https://realm.io/) and I'm trying to model this JSON, I'm working with [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper) too

```
  {
    companies: [
        {
             id: "1",
             name: "Quisque ut",
             logo: "0",
             company_categories: [
                "1",
                "2"
             ]
        }
    ],
    categories: [
        {
             id: "1",
             name: "Category1"
        },
        {
             id: "2",
             name: "Category2"
        },
        {
             id: "3",
             name: "Category3" 
        }
    ]
 }
```

In my app this is the code i'm implementing

```
class Category: Object, Mappable {
    dynamic var id = ""
    dynamic var name = ""

    required convenience init?(map: Map) {
        self.init()
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        id <- map["id"]
        name <- map["name"]
    }

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

and my object company is like this:

```
class Company: Object, Mappable {
    dynamic var id = ""
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var logo = ""
    let categories = List<Category>()

    required convenience init?(map: Map) {
        self.init()
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        id <- map["id"]
        name <- map["name"]
        logo <- map["logo"]

        var categories: [String]? = nil
        categories <- map["company_categories"]
        let realm = try! Realm()

        categories?.forEach { category in
            let categoryObject = realm.objects(Company.self).filter({ $0.id == category }).first
            self.categories.append(categoryObject!)
        }
    }

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

and I got an error like this:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Can not add objects from a different Realm'

Comment: My advice is to try all the process without ObjectMapper. I think that the problem is in the references, if the reference is crucial for Realm the new object which ObjectMapper create is the problem.             And you have wrong logic in the code in my opinion connected with (let categories = List<Category>()), first the way you declare the variable, second the way you try to retrieve the Categories, third why is nested in the class but not nested in the JSON this is not the way how programming work and ObjectMapper also.    Good luck.

Comment: I agree with Damyan. Also, the code fragments you've shared aren't complete, there's at least one compilation error (`realm.objects(Company.self)` should be `realm.objects(Category.self)`), you haven't shared how to trigger the exception you're seeing (a quick try at `Company(JSONString: ...` doesn't work with the JSON you provided because you have an array of Company objects). You'll need to provide more information for others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

if I correctly understood your question you need to use TransformType to explain how to map List

```
override func mapping(map: Map) {
    location <- map["location"]
    list <- (map["company_categories"], RealmListTransform<Category>())
}
```

here is an extension I use for it

```
class RealmListTransform<T: Object>: TransformType where T: Mappable {

typealias Object = List<T>
typealias JSON = [[String: Any]]

let mapper = Mapper<T>()

func transformFromJSON(_ value: Any?) -> List<T>? {
    let result = List<T>()
    if let tempArr = value as? [Any] {
        for entry in tempArr {
            let mapper = Mapper<T>()
            let model: T = mapper.map(JSONObject: entry)!
            result.append(model)
        }
    }
    return result
}

func transformToJSON(_ value: Object?) -> JSON? {
    var results = [[String:Any]]()
    if let value = value {
        for obj in value {
            let json = mapper.toJSON(obj)
            results.append(json)
        }
    }
    return results
}
```

}